# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. What do I do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to send my new app to apple to go on the app store, but i can't seem to get the code signing right!

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
>   (-19011)
>       Executable=/Users/Joseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicADay-dzlmpdarkaqeclhampzrztoxctto/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/PicADay.app/PicADay
>       codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
>       Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier,
>   864RCJ7A4Q.com.ProJaxsGames.PicADay
>       Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers, {type = mutable-small, count = 1, values
>   = (
>         0 : {contents = "864RCJ7A4Q.com.ProJaxsGames.PicADay"}
>       )}
>       AssertMacros: filter_entitlements(entitlements_whitelist, entitlements_requested, allowable_entitlements),  file:
>   codesign_wrapper.c, line: 932
>        - (null)

Comment: Was the distribution certificate created using an Application ID that has iCloud enabled? Note that if you create a certificate, then enable iCloud for that app, the certificate must be revoked, then re-created.

Answer (score 0):

**It is very Simple**.... Do follow this link... A step by step procedure for App Submit.... and if still you are not able to do. Reply me i will personally help you. ok All The Best.. :))

This is the [Link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/). Hope It helps..